# How replace config file with Angular 13?

Tags: json, angular, angular13

The error I'm getting is:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1" must have required property 'src'.
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1/replace" must match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".
  Data path "/fileReplacements/1" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

My angular.json:

```
...
"production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    },
    {
        "replace": "src/web.config",
        "with": "src/web.prod.config"
    }]
...
}
```

I upgraded to Angular 13 and now I'm getting an error when trying to build a prod version using this command: ng build --prod

What can I do with this? Is this an Angular 13 bug? should I use a different approach?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There must be something else going I think? This format hasn’t changed in a while. What happens when you just use ng build (without —prod, this has changed, prod is now default)

Comment: The problem here is that .config extension does not match the regex "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$"

Comment: @KSoze, I know but how do i replace the files now?

Comment: If the extension of the files you want to replace has to be `.config` you cannot using the fileReplacements of Angular.
You can try creating your own script and set it as 'postbuild' script.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it:

```
...
"production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    },
    "assets": [
        "src/web.config",
        {
            "glob": "web.config",
            "input": "src/iis/prod/",
            "output": "./"
        }]
...
}
```